# Remove/Disable internal javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to remove/disable internal JavaScript on a page after 'X' minutes so that it does not work at all after 'X' minutes of time?

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Programmatically, or do you want to disable just for your browser?  You can go into your browser settings and turn javascript off.  For timing, you can use a stopwatch or good ole' one miss-i-ssi-pi, two miss-i-ssi-pi.  But with JavaScript itself, you do not have the ability to disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below,

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="hideAfter">

    // your code here...


    // it will removes the script tag after 10 sec...
    setTimeout(function () {
        var ele = document.getElementById("hideAfter");
        ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele);
    }, 10000);

</script>
```

Comment: Removing a `script` node of an already parsed and evaluated script will just remove the node from the DOM. The code that was defined there will still exist.

Comment: For this case, we need to stop the functionality inside the script block before going to remove.. otherwise the operations are performed in the memory.. But i don't know exactly this is the efficient way.. but this is one of the possible way..

Comment: Your answer indicates that removing the `script` node would have an effect to the code that was loaded by that node - that it would stop running, disappear from memory or that it would not be possible to call it anymore - but this is not the case.